# add javascript variable in image url

Tags: javascript

My Random Number Generate code is

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*99999)
```

Now I want to put this variable output in a image scr url..

Here is my url

```
<img src="http://www.myexample.com/get/image.php?vcid=14851&t=481" alt="" id="imge"/>
```

So what will my code?

```
<img src="http://www.myexample.com/get/image.php?vcid='+ randomnumber +'&t=481" alt="" id="imge"/>
```

??

Please help me

Comment: Are there multiple images, or just one?

Comment: In your second .src line, replace the single-quotes with double-quotes.

Comment: @DavidThomas Its a captcha  image

Comment: Already tried.. Not work :( @vernonner3voltazim

Comment: Perhaps you should show us what the PHP code does with the received URL data?  (My previous comment was related to, "no need to pass the random number as a string", which is what happens when you use those single-quotes.)  There ARE ways in which PHP can fail to transmit an image.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Javascript you could do it like

```
var randomNumber = 1;
var image = document.getElementById("imageId");
var imageSrc = image.getAttribute("src");
image.setAttribute("src", imageSrc + randomNumber);
```

To put your number at the correct place you could use some string split functions, but since the order of query strings don't matter you should just put your `vcid` query at the end.

Comment: I change your last line and Its work for me..

last line will be:
 document.getElementById("imge").setAttribute("src", imageSrc + randomNumber);

So... Code will be

 <script>
 var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*99999)
 var imageSrc = document.getElementById("imge").getAttribute("src");
 document.getElementById("imge").setAttribute("src", imageSrc + randomnumber);
 </script>

Comment: you're right, i forgot to declare the image variable. i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your `<script>`:

```
document.getElementById("imge").src = "http://www.myexample.com/get/image.php?vcid=" + randomnumber + "&t=481";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('imge');

img.src = img.src.replace(/vcid=(\d+)/, function(){
  return randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
});
// purely to see the src has been changed, this is *not* relevant or required
img.title = img.src;
```

```html
<img src="http://www.myexample.com/get/image.php?vcid=14851&t=481" alt="" id="imge"/>
```

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).